# Single application with multiple programs in Java

Tags: java, eclipse

We're building an application that consists of several subprograms. Each of these subprograms are written in Java and share some common code. They are meant to be run as separate command-line utilities in a Linux environment.

**What is the logical way to structure this kind of application in Eclipse?** For now I'm thinking of: a) single Eclipse project with multiple classes and b) one Eclipse project for each of the subprograms and a project for common code.

*Additional information:*

Some of these subprograms would do primarily number-crunching, while other programs would use some graphics library to display information, while others would be simply manipulating files.

Evidently, the application covers a very wide area of functionality, therefore I am more inclined to the idea of packaging it into separate projects - *but I'm not sure how well would that work with Eclipse*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a maven [multi-module](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html) project. Eclipse works fine with maven projects.

You can use separate modules for subprograms. You can even make your subprograms component-based. That will allow you to have utility modules shared among your subprograms.

For example, if you encapsulate graphic processing code in a module, you can add it as a dependency to all subprograms that need graphic processing capability.

---

For all those who are having problems with getting Egit to cooperate with multi-module Maven projects, please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20981445/how-am-i-supposed-to-work-with-multi-module-maven-projects-with-egit/21007182#21007182).

Comment: Thanks, but would you care to elaborate?

Comment: @yannbane I've updated the answer. Happy to explain if you have any specific question regarding the structure.