# Do I have to use Maven modules for this or will plain projects be enough?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependencies, project

I'm working on an application that will have a set of core classes, a set of smaller tool programs which will use/share/depend on these core classes to generate data (e.g. like a game and various editors for items, levels, models), and I also have a launcher (or several) that is used to launch the application.

The tools and the launcher both depend on the core classes (both a level editor (tool) and a game (launcher) have to know what a level is (part of core classes)).

Can I just use three Maven projects for this? One for the core classes, one for the launcher(s), and one for the tools? And then add the dependencies?

Before I thought I would have to create a more elaborate structure involving parent projects and modules, but is that really necessary/conventional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both ways are convinient. You can start thinking from following points:

1. is there a part of your classes that should not be exposed to someone? eg server classes are running only on your server, and you want to keep them in separate jar file and not share to the public - for that you want to separate modules;
2. is your system will have a large number of classes? separating to modules will also separate concerns, you probably will have many test cases and separating to modules will help you run specific tests set from one little module faster than all tests from one big module;
3. will you plan to expose some of your classes to another application? Extracting that classes to separate module will not expose other part of your application;
4. if previous points doesn't votes for separating - you probably should start with one module, it is simple, I seen many projects that use singlemodule approach and you can switch to multymodule anytime.

PS.
If you selected multymodule implementations, don't create to many high granular modules.

Comment: So one parent project and then these modules, that's what you're suggesting? How do plain projects prevent any of that, though?

Comment: if you choosed multymodule apprach - creation of at least one parent project is recommended. Within its pom.xml you may define many common things, such as variables, versions of external dependencies and build entire project with one "mvn install" shot

Comment: Hm, that sounds really useful. I guess I will need to find some way to actually get it to work on Eclipse.

Comment: latest version of eclipse supports maven modules importing. Or you can use mvn eclipse:eclipse to generate related eclipse project files.

Comment: Tsaplin, well, if you're interested, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20981445/how-am-i-supposed-to-work-with-multi-module-maven-projects-with-egit). If the answer is to be trusted, it's currently impossible to do what I want.

Comment: Have looked your another question. I'am not familiar with another project types (jar types). But if your child projects will be maven oriented - contain theirs own pom.xml refering to parent/pom.xml, all will be working with eclipse too. Also I not used any of eclipse's git plugins - just cloning to separate folder and importing to workspace.